# Target a specific css class with the same name as another css class in the same application?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

In the Master page of my webform app I reference a .css file which contains a .tooltip class.  All the pages in my web app use this master page.  Now, in one particular page I am using a JQuery function that I got from a sample app, and this JQuery function uses a .tooltip class from a .css that came with the sample (which is different from the .tooltip class in the Master page of my web app).  How can I use the .tooltip css class that came with the JQuery sample on this one page and ignore the .tooltip class from the Master page?  I cannot modify the .tooltip class name from the JQuery sample, and it would be prohibitively time consuming to rename the .tooltip class from the Master page.  What is the workaround for this?

Here is the css

```
style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    body
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    table
    {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    table th
    {
        background-color: #F7F7F7;
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    table th, table td
    {
        padding: 5px;
        border-color: #ccc;
    }
    .tooltip
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 3;
        display: none;
        background-color: #2840B8;
        color: White;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    table td
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hiddencol
      {
        display: none;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: Where you are linking the jquery's css? At the starting of the particular page? Or at the en?

Comment: Globally replacing your `.tooltip` with `.master-tooltip` isn't an option? That is, a one-click find-and-replace across all the files. All the text editors I coded in support that function

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ASP.net, I assume that you can add a few lines of code to the Master page/template.

On your Master page/template, in the section where you link to the CSS files, add a conditional (if statement) to check for the name of the particular page that needs the special CSS file.

For the particular page, add a link to the additional CSS file such that it appears AFTER the standard CSS files.

The `.tooltip` rules in the bottom most CSS file will override the rules in the earlier CSS files, and that will probably take care of the issue.

Then only word of caution would be if `tooptip` appears in rules with other classes and selectors, then you may have to make sure that all the rules in the earlier CSS files are over-ridden in the bottom most CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using to generate these HTML pages, you can exclude `.tooltip` for that one page. To do this:

- Take `.tooltip` out of the Master CSS and put it into its own file.
- Include the new `.tooltip` CSS file only in the pages that you want it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be adding a class to the body in all your pages except this specific page and then changing your definition of the ".tooltip" to ".body-class .tooltip"

This way if the body class is not present your tooltip rule will not effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for these replies.  As usual, the app is in "Re-design" mode, convoluted (huge, ...).  The original css is integrated all over the place, and each page has to look alike (gov).  Is there a way I could define the css for this JQuery function and use it like in a div id="someID" class="something" ...

and then I place the JQuery in here ?

The page is actually a user control -- contained in a .aspx page which uses the Master page.  So would the div ...> idea be a way I could bypass the .tooltip from the Master page?  (that .tooltip css is contained in a .css file referenced in the Master page).